# Add a column inside csv files with column values as name of the 'folder' it is located in

Tags: python, csv, directory, iteration, os.path

I have multiple folders and multiple csv files inside each folder. I want to add a column inside each of these csv files with the name of the folder which is timestamp

ex:
20211307

--abc.csv
--def.csv

20211306

--abc.csv
--def.csv

20211305

--abc.csv
--def.csv

Can anything be written using os.path by iterating through folder and files

Comment: Yes, it can. But you have to add some more information about the folder structure involved. And you should also add your own attempt to solve your task and point out where you got stuck (errors etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) rather than os.path, and if you're happy to process each file as a pandas DataFrame, you could

- iterate through a glob() of .csv files,
- read each file into a DataFrame,
- insert a column with the name of the file's parent,
- overwrite the file with the revised DataFrame.  This probably doesn't work right the first time so you want to **back up your files** before you run it!  Better yet might be to write with a new filename, and once you're happy with the results you can come back and tidy up to get rid of the original files and rename the new ones if necessary.  In the sample code below I've commented out the crucial line that would overwrite the file, for safety.  Even so additional safety measure are advisable to ensure only the intended files get modified, as noted by [@timus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14311263/timus)

---

```
import pandas as pd    
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('.')

for fname in p.glob('**/*.csv'):
    print(fname.as_posix())
    parent = fname.parent.name
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    df.insert(0, 'parent', parent)
    print(df)
    ## df.to_csv(fname, index=False)
```

Output is something like this:

```
123/f2.csv
  parent  a
0    123  1
1    123  2
123/f1.csv
  parent  a
0    123  1
1    123  2
124/f2.csv
  parent  a
0    124  1
1    124  2
124/f1.csv
  parent  a
0    124  1
1    124  2
```

Comment: That's a neat solution. You might want to add `import pandas as pd`. Your solution could be a bit dangerous: It's not clear to me if there are really no restriction regarding the folders to process (hence my comment). Btw., just in case you don't know, you don't need `pathlib`, `glob.glob` from the standard library would work too (I prefer the `pathlib`, though).

Comment: Good spot on pandas, so I've added that--the hazards of not restarting the kernel to start with a clean slate. "could be a bit dangerous"--very much so, and I thought it might be worth elevating that into the answer for prominence.  Good to know about glob.glob, but I always go straight to pathlib just because I don't know any better.